# Error While Running Snort

Tags: snort

I have been trying to get snort IDS to work, but I having some difficulty. When I run snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l /var/log/snort I keep getting this error.

Initializing rule chains...
Warning: /etc/snort/rules/dos.rules(42) => threshold (in rule) is deprecated; use detection_filter instead.
ERROR: /etc/snort/rules/community-virus.rules(19) => !any is not allowed

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

***Warning: /etc/snort/rules/dos.rules(42) => threshold (in rule) is deprecated***

Just a warning. It should still work, but in the future this rule may stop working as written.

***ERROR: /etc/snort/rules/community-virus.rules(19) => !any is not allowed***

You have rules utilizing a variable that is being negated.  In a fresh install, this is often seen when you fail to set a range for $HOME_NET in your snort.conf.  By default it is set to:

`ipvar HOME_NET any`

So if a rule uses `!$HOME_NET`, (which many VRT rules do) snort throws an error. Resolution can be as simple as setting the subnet for your home network.  For example:

`ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.1.1/24`

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the following lines in from your rules files? It appears that there are problems on lines 42 and 19 (respectively).

lines 30-50 from dos.rules

lines 10-30 from community-virus.rules